Synchronizing an embedded system with RTOS
I wrote this code for a make-up assignment to pass one of my college class and graduate from my program in the field of electronic and embedded system.
It's pretty much the realization of a solar tracking system for solar panel. However, I'm using cheap servo motors for this instead of more appropriate motors. BTW I'm working with an ESP32-PICO-Kit v4.1 using the Arduino IDE.
IMPORTANT: This assignment has strict guide lines I must follow. So don't ask me why I wrote my code this way instead of any other way that would have been way more efficient. I agree this code would be better if written differently, but had to do it the way the teacher imposed. Has it serves to evaluate how well I've learned and mastered the concept seen in class.
Currently, my system works fine. However, the servos move in ticks, like the hands of a clock, instead of smooth continuous movement. I'm assuming it has something to do with my current low skill level in task synchronization. Could you please give me some feedback on how I could improved the synchronization of all tasks (without having to rewrote everything). Maybe my current results are as good as it could gets given the guide lines of the assignment, but I wonder if there's anything I could improve on speed up the movement ?
There are 9 required task:

(#1 to #4)vLireCapteur1-4: 4 tasks to read the analog value of each pins with LDR as light sensors and calculate the average value every 500ms (thanks to a timer). Then send the value to another task through a queue. After sending the value, the task also release a BIT for an event group. The task has to wait until the value in the queue is received before going forward. If one sensor is disconnected, the associated task must block itself and trigger the WDT.
(#5)vCompteur500ms(): A timer, formerly another task, that sends notifications to vLireCapteur[1-4] every 500ms.
(#6)vCalculePosition(): A task that waits for the all BITS of the event group. It then read all queues and store the values in them into buffers to perform the necessary math operation for the solar tracker. It then increment or decrement the current tilt or rotation value before sending said values to other tasks for setting the servos.
(#7)vPositionnerMoteurRotation(): This task set the position of the servo motor that rotates the (imaginary) solar panel. However, I must only write a new position if the value is different than the previous one.
(#8)vPositionnerMoteurInclinaison(): Same as the previous task, it controls the position of the servo the tilt angle of the solar panel. Like for the rotation, I only send the angle value if it's different than the previous one.
The last requested task (#9), is an interrupt (isrHandler() + vInterrupt()) that suspend all tasks, set the servomotors to 0° and wait 10 seconds before resuming the tasks operation. The interrupt is triggered with a button press. The task vInterrupt has the highest priority, but is suspended by default and wait to be resumed from the ISR by the isrHandler function.

I've also added one last task that has the exclusive access to the serial port/serial monitor. vPrintSerial is a gatekeeper task that use a queue to receive strings of text from other task to print error messages or other information. Using it allows me to avoid the use of semaphore or mutex to control the access to the serial port by multiple task.
I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but I won't translate all my comments from French (my native language) to english. There are just too many of them.
//Inclusion des libraries
#include <esp_task_wdt.h>
#include <freertos/event_groups.h>
#include <freertos/queue.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include <freertos/timers.h>
#include <freertos/semphr.h>

//Définition de macro
//Entrées analogique pour les photorésistances
#define LDR1_PIN 35
#define LDR2_PIN 34
#define LDR3_PIN 38
#define LDR4_PIN 37
//Bits pour les évènements de groupe xCalculeEvent et xChangeEvent
#define BIT0 (1 << 0)
#define BIT1 (1 << 1)
#define BIT2 (1 << 2)
#define BIT3 (1 << 3)
//Broches pour les servomoteurs
#define SERVO_V_PIN 13  //Broche pour l'inclinaison
#define SERVO_H_PIN 14  //Broche pour la rotation
//Broche pour l'interruption
#define INTERRUPT_PIN 27

#define STACKDEPTH_VALUE 3000

#define DATA_ACQUISITION_PERIOD 500

#define THRESHOLD 50

#define READ_2_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define READ_1_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define READ_3_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define READ_4_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define ROTATION_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define TILT_QUEUE_SIZE 1
#define SERIAL_QUEUE_SIZE 10
#define SERIAL_QUEUE_NB_CARACTERES 50

#define TILT_START_ANGLE 35
#define TILT_MAX_ANGLE 45
#define TILT_MIN_ANGLE 0
#define TILT_REST_ANGLE 0
#define TILT_INCR_DECR_VALUE 1
#define ROTATION_START_ANGLE 90
#define ROTATION_MAX_ANGLE 180
#define ROTATION_MIN_ANGLE 0
#define ROTATION_REST_ANGLE 0
#define ROTATION_INCR_DECR_VALUE 2

#define READ_LIGHT_1_PRIORITY 1
#define READ_LIGHT_2_PRIORITY 1
#define READ_LIGHT_3_PRIORITY 1
#define READ_LIGHT_4_PRIORITY 1
#define CALCULE_PRIORITY 3
#define INCLINAISON_PRIORITY 2
#define ROTATION_PRIORITY 2
#define SERIAL_PRIORITY 4
#define INTERRUPT_PRIORITY 5

#define TEST_MODE 0

#define TICK_10 pdMS_TO_TICKS(10)
#define TICK_50 pdMS_TO_TICKS(50)
#define TICK_100 pdMS_TO_TICKS(100)
#define TICK_250 pdMS_TO_TICKS(250)
#define TICK_500 pdMS_TO_TICKS(500)
#define TICK_1S pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000)
#define TICK_10S pdMS_TO_TICKS(10000)

/*Handle pour les évènements de groupe*/
EventGroupHandle_t xCalculeEvent;

/*Handle pour les tâches*/
TaskHandle_t hCapteur1Handle;
TaskHandle_t hCapteur2Handle;
TaskHandle_t hCapteur3Handle;
TaskHandle_t hCapteur4Handle;
TaskHandle_t hSerialHandle;
TaskHandle_t hCalculeHandle;
TaskHandle_t hRotationHandle;
TaskHandle_t hInclinaisonHandle;
TaskHandle_t hInterruptHandle;

/*Handle pour les files*/
QueueHandle_t xFileCapteur1;
QueueHandle_t xFileCapteur2;
QueueHandle_t xFileCapteur3;
QueueHandle_t xFileCapteur4;
QueueHandle_t xFileMoteurRotation;
QueueHandle_t xFileMoteurInclinaison;
QueueHandle_t xSerialQueue;

TimerHandle_t xTimerAcquisition;

/*Configuration pour le WatchDog Timer (WDT)*/
esp_task_wdt_config_t wdt_config = {
  .timeout_ms = 30000,    //Délais de 30 secondes
  .idle_core_mask = 0,
  .trigger_panic = true,  //Réinitialiser le programme quand le wdt se déclanche
};

/*Déclaration des servomoteurs*/
Servo Rotation;
Servo Inclinaison;

//Interrupt function
void IRAM_ATTR isrHandler(void){
  xTaskResumeFromISR(hInterruptHandle);
}

//Task for reading light sensor #1
void vLireCapteur1(void *pvParameters){
  pinMode(LDR1_PIN, INPUT);
  unsigned int uiMoyPre=0, uiMoyenne=0, uiNbMesure=0, uiTest;
  #if TEST_MODE
    String sTestString;
    char pcMsgTx[SERIAL_QUEUE_NB_CARACTERES];
  #endif
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vLireCapteur1 actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    uiNbMesure++;

    #if TEST_MODE
      uiTest = analogRead(LDR1_PIN);
      uiMoyenne += uiTest;
      sTestString = String("Valeur de mesure: ");
      sTestString += uiTest;
      sTestString += ", Valeur total: ";
      sTestString += uiMoyenne;
      sTestString += ", #";
      sTestString += uiNbMesure;
      sTestString.toCharArray(pcMsgTx, SERIAL_QUEUE_NB_CARACTERES);
      xQueueSend(xSerialQueue, pcMsgTx, 0);
    #else
      uiMoyenne += analogRead(LDR1_PIN);
    #endif

    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
    if(ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 0) == pdPASS){
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne/uiNbMesure; //Calcule de la moyenne
      //Si que le capteur est déconnecté et analogRead() retourne 0, attendre indéfiniment jusqu'à ce que le WDT se déclenche et réinitialise le système
      while(analogRead(LDR1_PIN) == 0) vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
      //Envoie à la file xFileCapteur1
      if(xQueueSend(xFileCapteur1, &uiMoyenne, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
        xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileCapteur1",0);
      }
      xEventGroupSetBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT0);  //Envoie du BIT0 pour l'évènement de groupe xCalculeEvent
      while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur1) > 0){
        vTaskDelay(TICK_100);   //Attendre tant est aussi longtemps que la valeur dans la file n'a pas été récupérée
        esp_task_wdt_reset();   //Réinitialisation du WDT à fin d'éviter que toutes les tâches vLireCapteur#() ne déclanche le WDT quand une ou plusieurs se bloque. Permet de savoir quel(s) capteur(s) est/sont problématique(s)
      }
      //Réinitialisation des valeurs
      uiMoyPre = uiMoyenne;
      uiNbMesure = 0;
      uiMoyenne = 0;
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
  }
}


//Task for reading light sensor #2
void vLireCapteur2(void *pvParameters){
  pinMode(LDR2_PIN, INPUT);
  unsigned int uiMoyPre=0, uiMoyenne=0, uiNbMesure=0;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vLireCapteur2 actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    uiNbMesure++;
    uiMoyenne += analogRead(LDR2_PIN);
    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
    if(ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 0) == pdPASS){
      //Calcule de la moyenne
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne/uiNbMesure;
      //Si que le capteur est déconnecté et analogRead() retourne 0, attendre indéfiniment jusqu'à ce que le WDT se déclenche et réinitialise le système
      while(analogRead(LDR2_PIN) == 0) vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
      //Envoie à la file xFileCapteur2
      if(xQueueSend(xFileCapteur2, &uiMoyenne, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
        xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileCapteur2",0);
      }
      xEventGroupSetBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT1);    //Envoie du BIT1 pour l'évènement de groupe xCalculeEvent
      while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur2) > 0) {
        vTaskDelay(TICK_100);    //Attendre tant est aussi longtemps que la valeur dans la file n'a pas été récupérée
        esp_task_wdt_reset();   //Réinitialisation du WDT à fin d'éviter que toutes les tâches vLireCapteur#() ne déclanche le WDT quand une ou plusieurs se bloque. Permet de savoir quel(s) capteur(s) est/sont problématique(s)
      }
      //Réinitialisation des valeurs
      uiMoyPre = uiMoyenne;
      uiNbMesure = 0;
      uiMoyenne = 0;
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
  }
}


//Task for reading light sensor #3
void vLireCapteur3(void *pvParameters){
  pinMode(LDR3_PIN, INPUT);
  unsigned int uiMoyPre=0, uiMoyenne=0, uiNbMesure=0;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vLireCapteur3 actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    uiNbMesure++;
    uiMoyenne += analogRead(LDR3_PIN);
    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
    if(ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 0) == pdPASS){
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne/uiNbMesure;   //Calcule de la moyenne
      //Si que le capteur est déconnecté et analogRead() retourne 0, attendre indéfiniment jusqu'à ce que le WDT se déclenche et réinitialise le système
      while(analogRead(LDR3_PIN) == 0) vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
      //Envoie à la file xFileCapteur3
      if(xQueueSend(xFileCapteur3, &uiMoyenne, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
        xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileCapteur3",0);
      }
      xEventGroupSetBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT2);    //Envoie du BIT2 pour l'évènement de groupe xCalculeEvent
      while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur3) > 0) {
        vTaskDelay(TICK_100);    //Attendre tant est aussi longtemps que la valeur dans la file n'a pas été récupérée
        esp_task_wdt_reset();   //Réinitialisation du WDT à fin d'éviter que toutes les tâches vLireCapteur#() ne déclanche le WDT quand une ou plusieurs se bloque. Permet de savoir quel(s) capteur(s) est/sont problématique(s)
      }
      //Réinitialisation des valeurs
      uiMoyPre = uiMoyenne;
      uiNbMesure = 0;
      uiMoyenne = 0;
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
  }
}


//Task for reading light sensor #4
void vLireCapteur4(void *pvParameters){
  pinMode(LDR4_PIN, INPUT);
  unsigned int uiMoyPre=0, uiMoyenne=0, uiNbMesure=0;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vLireCapteur4 actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    uiNbMesure++;
    uiMoyenne += analogRead(LDR4_PIN);
    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
    if(ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 0) == pdPASS){
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne/uiNbMesure;   //Calcule de la moyenne
      //Si que le capteur est déconnecté et analogRead() retourne 0, attendre indéfiniment jusqu'à ce que le WDT se déclenche et réinitialise le système
      while(analogRead(LDR4_PIN) == 0) vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
      //Envoie à la file xFileCapteur4
      if(xQueueSend(xFileCapteur4, &uiMoyenne, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
        xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileCapteur4",0);
      }
      xEventGroupSetBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT3);    //Envoie du BIT3 pour l'évènement de groupe xCalculeEvent
      while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur4) > 0) {
        vTaskDelay(TICK_100);    //Attendre tant est aussi longtemps que la valeur dans la file n'a pas été récupérée
        esp_task_wdt_reset();   //Réinitialisation du WDT à fin d'éviter que toutes les tâches vLireCapteur#() ne déclanche le WDT quand une ou plusieurs se bloque. Permet de savoir quel(s) capteur(s) est/sont problématique(s)
      }
      //Réinitialisation des valeurs
      uiMoyPre = uiMoyenne;
      uiNbMesure = 0;
      uiMoyenne = 0;
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
  }
}

//The 500ms timer
void vCompteur500ms(TimerHandle_t xTimerAcquisition){
  xTaskNotifyGive(hCapteur1Handle);
  xTaskNotifyGive(hCapteur2Handle);
  xTaskNotifyGive(hCapteur3Handle);
  xTaskNotifyGive(hCapteur4Handle);
}

//Task that calculate the sun's position
void vCalculePosition(void *pvParameters){
  unsigned int uiMoy1, uiMoy2, uiMoy3, uiMoy4;   //Buffer pour les moyennes individuelles des capteurs
  unsigned int uiRotationAngle = ROTATION_START_ANGLE;  //L'angle du servomoteur de rotation
  unsigned int uiTiltAngle = TILT_START_ANGLE;  //L'angle du servomoteur d'inclinaison
  int iMoyH,iMoyB,iMoyG,iMoyD;  //Moyennes selon la direction cartésienne (Haut, Bas, Gauche, Droite)
  int iDiff_Inc, iDiff_Rot;   //Différence pour les moyennes Haut et Bas (iDiff_Inc) et les moyennes Gauche et Droite (iDiff_Rot
  EventBits_t uxBits;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vCalculePosition actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    uxBits = xEventGroupWaitBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT0|BIT1|BIT2|BIT3, pdTRUE, pdTRUE, 0);   //Attendre les BIT 0 à 3 avant de poursuivre
    // uxBits = xEventGroupWaitBits(xCalculeEvent, BIT0|BIT1|BIT2|BIT3, pdTRUE, pdTRUE, TICK_500);   //Attendre les BIT 0 à 3 avant de poursuivre
    //Exécuter le code suivant si tous les BITS sont reçuent.
    if((uxBits & (BIT0|BIT1|BIT2|BIT3)) == (BIT0|BIT1|BIT2|BIT3)){
      //Réception des messages en attentes dans les files
      if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur1) > 0) xQueueReceive(xFileCapteur1, &uiMoy1, 0);   //Réception de la valeur de la file xFileCapteur1
      if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur2) > 0) xQueueReceive(xFileCapteur2, &uiMoy2, 0);   //Réception de la valeur de la file xFileCapteur2
      if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur3) > 0) xQueueReceive(xFileCapteur3, &uiMoy3, 0);   //Réception de la valeur de la file xFileCapteur3
      if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileCapteur4) > 0) xQueueReceive(xFileCapteur4, &uiMoy4, 0);   //Réception de la valeur de la file xFileCapteur4
      //Si la valeur d'au moins un des buffers est encore 0, dû à l'échec de la réception de la valeur ou dû à la réception d'une valeur erronée, suspendre le reste de l'exécution du code pour déclencher le WDT dans 30s
      while(uiMoy1 == 0 || uiMoy2 == 0 || uiMoy3 == 0 || uiMoy4 == 0);
      //Calcule des moyennes des positions cartésiennes (Haut,Bas,Gauche,Droite)
      iMoyH = (uiMoy1 + uiMoy2) / 2;   //Moyenne Haut
      iMoyB = (uiMoy3 + uiMoy4) / 2;   //Moyenne Bas
      iMoyG = (uiMoy1 + uiMoy3) / 2;   //Moyenne Gauche
      iMoyD = (uiMoy2 + uiMoy4) / 2;   //Moyenne Droite
      //Calcule de la différence entre les moyennes
      iDiff_Inc = iMoyH - iMoyB;  //Différence inclinaison (Haut - Bas)
      iDiff_Rot = iMoyG - iMoyD;  //Différence rotation (Gauche - Droite)
      if(abs(iDiff_Inc) > THRESHOLD){   //Si la valeur absolu de la différence entre les moyennes Haut et Bas est supérieur à la valeur de Tolérance (50)...
        if(iMoyH < iMoyB){    //Si la moyenne Haut est inférieur à la moyenne Bas
          uiTiltAngle += TILT_INCR_DECR_VALUE;   //Incrémenter l'angle du servo d'inclinaison
          //Si la valeur d'angle est suppérieur ou égal au seuil d'inclinaison maximale, définir l'angle comme étant la valeur maximale
          if(uiTiltAngle >= TILT_MAX_ANGLE) uiTiltAngle = TILT_MAX_ANGLE;       
        }else if(iMoyH > iMoyB){    //Si la moyenne Haut est supérieur à la moyenne Bas
          uiTiltAngle -= TILT_INCR_DECR_VALUE;   //Décrémenter l'angle du servo d'inclinaison
          //Si la valeur d'angle est inférieur ou égal au seuil d'inclinaison minimale, définir l'angle comme étant la valeur minimale
          if(uiTiltAngle <= TILT_MIN_ANGLE) uiTiltAngle = TILT_MIN_ANGLE;       
        }
        //Envoyer la valeur d'angle à la file xFileMoteurInclinaison
        if(xQueueSend(xFileMoteurInclinaison, &uiTiltAngle, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
          xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileMoteurInclinaison",0);
        }
      }
      if(abs(iDiff_Rot) > THRESHOLD){   //Si la valeur absolu de la différence entre les moyennes Gauche et Droite est supérieur à la valeur de Tolérance (50)...
        if(iMoyG < iMoyD){    //Si la moyenne Gauche est inférieur à la moyenne Droite
          uiRotationAngle += ROTATION_INCR_DECR_VALUE;   //Incrémenter l'angle du servo de rotation
          //Si la valeur d'angle est suppérieur ou égal au seuil de rotation maximale, définir l'angle comme étant la valeur maximale
          if(uiRotationAngle >= ROTATION_MAX_ANGLE) uiRotationAngle = ROTATION_MAX_ANGLE;
        }else if(iMoyG > iMoyD){    //Si la moyenne Gauche est supérieur à la moyenne Droite
          uiRotationAngle -= ROTATION_INCR_DECR_VALUE;   //Décrémenter l'angle du servo de rotation
          //Si la valeur d'angle est inférieur ou égal au seuil de rotation minimale, définir l'angle comme étant la valeur minimale
          if(uiRotationAngle <= ROTATION_MIN_ANGLE) uiRotationAngle = ROTATION_MIN_ANGLE;
        }
        //Envoyer la valeur d'angle à la file xFileMoteurRotation
        if(xQueueSend(xFileMoteurRotation, &uiRotationAngle, portMAX_DELAY) == pdFAIL){
          xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Echec de l'envoie a la file xFileMoteurRotation",0);
        }
      }
      //Remise à zéro des buffers
      uiMoy1 = uiMoy2 = uiMoy3 = uiMoy4 = 0;
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
    vTaskDelay(TICK_250);
  }
}

//Task that control the servo motor for the rotation
void vPositionnerMoteurRotation(void *pvParameters){
  Rotation.attach(SERVO_H_PIN);
  Rotation.write(ROTATION_START_ANGLE);
  unsigned int uiAngle;
  unsigned int uiAnglePre = ROTATION_START_ANGLE;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vPositionnerMoteurRotation actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileMoteurRotation) > 0){  //S'il y a un message en attente dans la file xFileMoteurRotation
      if(xQueueReceive(xFileMoteurRotation,&uiAngle,0) == pdTRUE){  //Récupère la valeur dans la file
        //Change l'angle du servo avec la valeur reçu, si cette dernière est différente de la précédente. Sauvegarder la valeur d'angle pour la prochaine exécution.
        if(uiAngle != uiAnglePre){
          Rotation.write(uiAngle);
          uiAnglePre = uiAngle;
        }
      }
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
    // vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
  }
}

//Task that control the servo motor for the tilt angle
void vPositionnerMoteurInclinaison(void *pvParameters){
  Inclinaison.attach(SERVO_V_PIN);
  Inclinaison.write(TILT_START_ANGLE);
  unsigned int uiAngle;
  unsigned int uiAnglePre = TILT_START_ANGLE;
  xQueueSend(xSerialQueue,"Tache vPositionnerMoteurInclinaison actif",0);
  for (;;) {
    if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileMoteurInclinaison) > 0){  //S'il y a un message en attente dans la file xFileMoteurInclinaison...
      if(xQueueReceive(xFileMoteurInclinaison,&uiAngle,0) == pdTRUE){  //Récupère la valeur dans la file
        //Change l'angle du servo avec la valeur reçu, si cette dernière est différente de la précédente. Sauvegarder la valeur d'angle pour la prochaine exécution.
        if(uiAngle != uiAnglePre){
          Inclinaison.write(uiAngle);
          uiAnglePre = uiAngle;
        }
      }
    }
    esp_task_wdt_reset();
    // vTaskDelay(TICK_100);
    vTaskDelay(TICK_50);
  }
}

//Task that manage the access to the serial monitor
void vPrintSerial(void *pvParameters){
  char pcMsgRx[SERIAL_QUEUE_NB_CARACTERES];
  Serial.println("Portier vPrintSerial actif");
  for(;;){
    if(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xSerialQueue) > 0){
      if(xQueueReceive(xSerialQueue, (char*)&pcMsgRx, 0) == pdPASS){
        Serial.println(pcMsgRx);
      }
    }
    vTaskDelay(TICK_250);
  }
}

//Task with the interruption routine
void vInterrupt(void *pvParameters){
  unsigned int uiRotationRest = ROTATION_REST_ANGLE, uiTiltRest = TILT_REST_ANGLE;

  for(;;){
    //Suspendre la tâche au démarrage.
    vTaskSuspend(NULL);

    //À la reprise de cette tâche, suspendre les tâches suivantes
    vTaskSuspend(hCapteur1Handle);
    vTaskSuspend(hCapteur2Handle);
    vTaskSuspend(hCapteur3Handle);
    vTaskSuspend(hCapteur4Handle);
    vTaskSuspend(hCalculeHandle);

    //Imprimer un message sur le port sériel et positionner les servos à 0°
    xQueueSend(xSerialQueue, "Ceci est une interruption.", 0);
    xQueueSend(xFileMoteurRotation, &uiRotationRest, 0);
    xQueueSend(xFileMoteurInclinaison, &uiTiltRest, 0);
    //Attendre que les files xSerialQueue, xFileMoteurRotation et xFileMoteurInclinaison soit vide avand de...
    while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xSerialQueue) > 0 || uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileMoteurRotation) > 0 || uxQueueMessagesWaiting(xFileMoteurInclinaison) > 0) vTaskDelay(50);

    //Suspendre les tâches restantes.
    vTaskSuspend(hSerialHandle);
    vTaskSuspend(hRotationHandle);
    vTaskSuspend(hInclinaisonHandle);

    //Attendre dix (10) secondes...
    vTaskDelay(TICK_10S);
    
    //Avant de reprendre toutes les tâches.
    vTaskResume(hCapteur1Handle);
    vTaskResume(hCapteur2Handle);
    vTaskResume(hCapteur3Handle);
    vTaskResume(hCapteur4Handle);
    vTaskResume(hCalculeHandle);
    vTaskResume(hInclinaisonHandle);
    vTaskResume(hRotationHandle);
    vTaskResume(hSerialHandle);
  }
}

void vCompteur10s(TimerHandle_t xTimerTaskResume){
  xTaskResumeAll();
}

//The Setup function
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);   //Début communication sérielle

  //Initialiser la pin d'interruption
  pinMode(INTERRUPT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT_PIN), isrHandler, RISING);

  //Création du compteur de 500ms
  xTimerAcquisition = xTimerCreate("xTimerAcquisition", pdMS_TO_TICKS(DATA_ACQUISITION_PERIOD), pdTRUE, 0, vCompteur500ms);
  xTimerStart(xTimerAcquisition,0);

  //Création des évènement de groupe
  xCalculeEvent = xEventGroupCreate();

  //Création des files
  xFileCapteur1 = xQueueCreate(READ_1_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xFileCapteur2 = xQueueCreate(READ_2_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xFileCapteur3 = xQueueCreate(READ_3_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xFileCapteur4 = xQueueCreate(READ_4_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xFileMoteurRotation = xQueueCreate(ROTATION_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xFileMoteurInclinaison = xQueueCreate(TILT_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(int));
  xSerialQueue = xQueueCreate(SERIAL_QUEUE_SIZE, SERIAL_QUEUE_NB_CARACTERES*sizeof(char));

  //Création des tâches
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vLireCapteur1, "vLireCapteur1", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, READ_LIGHT_1_PRIORITY, &hCapteur1Handle, 0);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vLireCapteur2, "vLireCapteur2", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, READ_LIGHT_2_PRIORITY, &hCapteur2Handle, 0);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vLireCapteur3, "vLireCapteur3", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, READ_LIGHT_3_PRIORITY, &hCapteur3Handle, 1);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vLireCapteur4, "vLireCapteur4", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, READ_LIGHT_4_PRIORITY, &hCapteur4Handle, 1);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vCalculePosition, "vCalculePosition", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, CALCULE_PRIORITY, &hCalculeHandle, 1);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vPositionnerMoteurRotation, "vPositionnerMoteurRotation", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, ROTATION_PRIORITY, &hRotationHandle, 1);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vPositionnerMoteurInclinaison, "vPositionnerMoteurInclinaison", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, INCLINAISON_PRIORITY, &hInclinaisonHandle, 0);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vPrintSerial, "vPrintSerial", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, SERIAL_PRIORITY, &hSerialHandle, 0);
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(vInterrupt, "vInterrupt", STACKDEPTH_VALUE, NULL, INTERRUPT_PRIORITY, &hInterruptHandle, 1);

  //Reconfiguration du wdt
  if(esp_task_wdt_reconfigure(&wdt_config)!= ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Erreur à l'initiation du watchdog");
  }

  //Attache du wdt aux tâches
  esp_task_wdt_add(hCapteur1Handle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hCapteur2Handle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hCapteur3Handle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hCapteur4Handle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hCalculeHandle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hRotationHandle);
  esp_task_wdt_add(hInclinaisonHandle);
}

void loop() {}
```


DRY
Parameterize, please.
Consider this example. Paste one function into /tmp/sensor2.c and
another function's text into /tmp/sensor3.c,
and then review $ git diff --word-diff /tmp/sensor{2,3}.c.
The two routines have randomly diverged in this way:
void vLireCapteur2(
      ...
      //Calcule de la moyenne
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne / uiNbMesure;

void vLireCapteur3(
      ...
      uiMoyenne = uiMoyenne / uiNbMesure;   //Calcule de la moyenne

Is one better?
No, they are the same thing.
Yet they are expressed in a slightly different way.
This frustrates subsequent maintenance and refactoring efforts, so nip it in the bud.
And then we see sensor3 was copy-n-pasted to read from sensor4.
The TEST_MODE behavior for sensor1 could be a call-out to a debug helper.
And then we might optionally enable debugging for any of the sensors.
consistent comments
/*Déclaration des servomoteurs*/
Servo Rotation;
Servo Inclinaison;

//Interrupt function
void IRAM_ATTR isrHandler(void){
  xTaskResumeFromISR(hInterruptHandle);
}

//Task for reading light sensor #1

Those last two comments are not great.
Pick a language, and stick with it.
The final comment should be //Tâche de lire du capteur n°1.
consistent identifiers
Mixing French and English words within a single identifier is not a good idea.
#define INCLINAISON_PRIORITY 2

This happens ubiquitously throughout the codebase.
Pick a language and stick with it.
Academia is not industry.
In an industrial context, maintainability of the code
by current and future teams is an important requirement.
Usually this boils down to a project guideline
of "identifiers shall be in English", even if
text for end users, and the internal comments,
are in another language.
Gratuitously obscuring the relationship between
that priorité and TILT_START_ANGLE is unhelpful.
These are good identifiers and good comments,
relying on the English words Vertical and Horizontal:
#define SERVO_V_PIN 13  //Broche pour l'inclinaison
#define SERVO_H_PIN 14  //Broche pour la rotation

These identifiers are less well chosen (though
the comments are terrific):
  int iMoyH, iMoyB, iMoyG, iMoyD;  //Moyennes selon la direction cartésienne (Haut, Bas, Gauche, Droite)

meaningful identifiers
Ok, now we're not even trying:
#define BIT0 (1 << 0)
#define BIT1 (1 << 1)
#define BIT2 (1 << 2)
#define BIT3 (1 << 3)

Yes, those are accurate statements.
No, they're not helpful.
They don't shed much light on what each quantity means.
BIT3 seems to indicate "reading obtained from sensor 4", I think?
Help out the poor maintenance engineer who will have
to read this code a year from now, when you're off doing other things.
review context
I found this comment difficult to read.
//Task that calculate the sun's position

That is, absent any description, I was unclear on the physical setup
of sensors, photovoltaics, and actuators, and I was
a little surprised it didn't mention "... the sun's RELATIVE position".
Heliotropic behaviors for sunflowers or robots are much
easier to describe in terms of relative light strength
received on one side or the other.
And then we can worry about hysteresis and control theory.

the servos move in ticks

Sounds like typical expected stepper motor behavior.
If you have some code which exercises the servos in a smoother manner,
it would be worth posting it.
And then we could look at instrumenting both bits of code
to log detailed timestamps, to isolate where the jerkiness comes from.
        if (uiAngle != uiAnglePre) {
          Inclinaison.write(uiAngle);

We don't know what model servo you're using and what it's physically
capable of. But if the tilt task often gets a commanded angle
which is off by much more than unity from the "pre" value,
then you may want to smooth things out here instead of
asking .write() to just jam in a radically different value.
Pause a moment between those small writes,
until the servo eventually arrives at the desired position.
The sun doesn't jump around much.
It's possible you can ask the servo to respond more slowly,
perhaps via a software setting or perhaps via a resistor jumper
or adjusting its supply voltage.
That might be enough to mitigate the annoying "tick" behavior.
Put another way, you are inventing a new Requirement here,
beyond merely saying "the PV array shall always point at the sun".
You're requiring not only that the array shall move,
but also that it shall move smoothly.
This is a great requirement.
We should formalize it, perhaps in terms
of max servo steps per minute or similar slew rate,
and then validate the physical behavior matches our expectations.
It is, of course, possible that the deployed equipment
is incapable of moving as smoothly as desired,
and can only do stepper motor increments.
Adding physical compliance (springiness)
and moment (weights) to the setup could give
us a more easily controlled system.
sunrise
I didn't notice any reference to wallclock time or an almanac,
which is fine. Tomorrow's sunrise will happen nearly when today's did.
The OP code will apparently point the array to the West overnight,
and then slew at maximum speed East the next morning.
This is a perfectly good approach, but it's one that is
worth explicitly documenting.
Other approaches might slowly pre-position the array facing East
so it's ready for the dawn, mimimizing the wear on motors,
or might attempt to optimize some other overnight maintenance aspect
like reduced exposure to damage from prevailing winds,
or attempting to point so evening rains will most effectively
wash away the day's dust.

"Pick a language and stick with it." I'd rather go as far as saying "Pick English and stick with it." I'm not native English either and I do have some serious experience from maintaining non-English code bases. It's always a mess! C uses English in itself. All technical terms are in English. There are a lot of technical terms and you must learn all those n technical terms in English no matter. So why would you at the same time also learn n additional useless technical terms in your native language - that's just creating a steeper learning curve for literally nothing gained.
